# how to resolve Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request) on PHP application htaccess

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, wamp

I'm maintaining a website not written by me.It Is written on PHP without framework.
I have try many configuration on vhost, htaccess running it xamp for windows.
with php -s localhost 8080.
the css file, medias files and javascript are not loading.

my configuration .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 8080
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^th/(.*)$ medias/images/thumb/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^bl/(.*)$ medias/docs/bl/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^invoice/(.*)$ medias/docs/factures/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^im/(.*)$ medias/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^do/(.*)$ medias/docs/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^vid/(.*)$ medias/videos/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The built-in php server does not support TLS (i.e. HTTPS). It is not intended for production use (it also only supports one concurrent request, for example).

Comment: but why i'm not able to launch it on xampp?

Comment: I don't know. But it also doesn't matter, because the error you mentioned is produced by the PHP built-in server when it receives a TLS handshake.

Comment: thank you very much!!